# Setting up libcurl on Linux

Tags: c, linux, curl

I'm trying to use `libcurl`, but am failing to set it up correctly. I've been reading the documentation for the past hours, but I'm confused and lost. (This is my first time using an external library with C)

Based on [these](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html) instructions, I've correctly configured and installed `libcurl` and `curl-config`. A minimal C program that simply includes `<curl/curl.h>` compiles; however, when I run any example program (say, [`chkspeed.c`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/chkspeed.html)), I get the following "undefined" errors.

```
/tmp/ccprXNBB.o: In function `main':
chkspeed.c:(.text+0x1bf): undefined reference to `curl_version'
chkspeed.c:(.text+0x408): undefined reference to `curl_global_init'
chkspeed.c:(.text+0x40d): undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
chkspeed.c:(.text+0x432): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
chkspeed.c:(.text+0x454): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
chkspeed.c:(.text+0x476): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
chkspeed.c:(.text+0x482): undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
chkspeed.c:(.text+0x4b0): undefined reference to `curl_easy_getinfo'
chkspeed.c:(.text+0x50b): undefined reference to `curl_easy_getinfo'
chkspeed.c:(.text+0x566): undefined reference to `curl_easy_getinfo'
chkspeed.c:(.text+0x5c9): undefined reference to `curl_easy_getinfo'
chkspeed.c:(.text+0x624): undefined reference to `curl_easy_getinfo'
chkspeed.c:(.text+0x66a): undefined reference to `curl_easy_strerror'
chkspeed.c:(.text+0x696): undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
chkspeed.c:(.text+0x69b): undefined reference to `curl_global_cleanup'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The following is my output for the three `curl-config` flags featured in this guide. I'm not sure how to use this information:

```
$: curl-config --cflags
-I/usr/local/include
$: curl-config --libs
-L/usr/local/lib -lcurl
$: curl-config --feature
IPv6
UnixSockets
libz
AsynchDNS
```

I would really appreciate any help that might get me in the right direction, if not solve the issue. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please show your command line(s) to compile and link the program. Your `CFLAGS` should include `-Wl,-R,<path to lib>` to ensure the correct library is used at runtime, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should compile it like this:

```
$ gcc chkspeed.c -o chkspeed $(curl-config --cflags) $(curl-config --libs)
```

so that the gcc command can have the proper `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` for compiling and linking against `libcurl`.

Note when working with a shell (like bash) and you execute a command like this:

```
$ cmd1 arg1 arg2 $(cmd2 arg3)
```

the shell will evaluate first `cmd arg3` by executing it and using the `stdout` output of `cmd2` as an argument of for `cmd1`. Let's say that `cmd2 arg3` prints (on `stdout`) `hello`, then the shell will execute `cmd1 arg1 arg2 hello`.

So

```
$ gcc chkspeed.c -o chkspeed $(curl-config --cflags) $(curl-config --libs)
```

will be executed as

```
$ gcc chkspeed.c -o chkspeed -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lcurl
```

because the output of `curl-config --cflags` is `-I/usr/local/include` and the output of `curl-config --libs` is `-L/usr/local/lib -lcurl`.

Comment: `CFLAGS` should include `-Wl,-R,<path to lib>` to ensure the correct library is used at runtime, too. It is not clear to me if that happens based on your answer. Can you show what `curl-config --cflags` produces?

Comment: Pablo's answer actually worked!
As specified in the question, `curl-config --cflags` yields `-I/usr/local/include`

Comment: @jww The OP posted the output in the question. On my system for example, --cflags is an empty string and --libs display `-lcurl -lssl -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lldap -llber -lz`.

Comment: @jww is that really necessary to use rpath here? Or do you think that this curl installation is not on system paths because the headers and shared libs are in `/usr/local`? I use gentoo, so I've been watching building software and the output of make for many years and I rarely see packages linking with rpath, some do but I would say most don't.

Comment: @Pablo - `ldd` will tell you. If you just use `curl-speed`, then it will tell you where the runtime linker is finding libraries. The Linux coreutil folks also say to use it when building their gear. What is more befuddling to me is, Linux still has not fixed the broken path problem after 25 years or so.

Comment: @jww I know that `ldd` shows you this information and I know about rpath, I like that for example cmake sets the rpath when compiling so that when you are testing  a program that links to one of you libraries, you don't have to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but when you do `make install`, cmake strips that information (at least my cmake builds do). Like I said from watching gentoo build thousands of packages, I see packages that link with rpath and others that don't ...

Comment: @jww my question was if for this particular test program (the OP's test program) using rpath is really necessary when the OP's libcurl seems to be in the system paths anyway.

Comment: @Pablo - As I understand it, if OP wants to runtime link to the library used during link, then both `-Wl,-R` and `-Wl,--enable-new-dtags` are needed. Otherwise, OP gets the first one the runtime linker finds (even if it is the wrong one). To say more we need more information, like the OS, the runtime linker configuration and the compile and link commands.

Comment: @jww ok, if that's the case, then I agree rpath should be use. But we don't know what the OP wants. On my system I only have one libcurl so I wouldn't use rpath because it's on my system path. Regardless, I think that the information you've provided is good, so I've upvoted your comment.

Comment: *On my system I only have one libcurl so I wouldn't use rpath..."* - Ah, there's the disconnect I am suffering. I assumed the system one was available but unwanted; and OP built the latest cURL and placed it in `/usr/local`, which is the desired one. Like I said, we need more information.

Comment: *Like I said, we need more information* agree. But I think the OP is happy with the result and is happy to use the first libcurls the system finds.